# Python code causes SQL server transaction log to increase exponentially

Tags: python, sql-server, transaction-log

I have a python script to execute a stored procedure to purge the tables in database. This SP further calls another SP which has delete statements for each table in database. Something like below -

Python calls - Stored procedure Purge_DB

Purge_DB calls - Stored procedure Purge_Table

Purge_Table has definition to delete data from each table.

When I run this python script, the transaction logs increase exponentially and on running this script 2-3 times, I get the transaction log full error.
Please note that the deletion happens in transaction.

BEGIN TRAN

```
        EXEC (@DEL_SQL) 


    COMMIT TRAN
```

Earlier I was executing the same SP using VB script and never got any issue related to transaction log.

Is there a different way that Python uses to create transaction log?
Why is the log size much bigger with Python than VB script?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now.

Python starts a transaction when execute method is called and that transaction remains open until we explicitly call commit() method. Since, this purge SP was called for more than 100 tables, the transaction log was populated until transaction was closed in the python code and hence, it was getting full because of this job.

I have set the autocommit property of pyodbc to true which will now automatically commit each SQL statement as and when it is executed as part of that connection. Please refer to the documentation here -

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Database-Transaction-Management